# Poisson Brackets Computation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, poisson-brackets

> Consider a particle of mass $m$ subjected to the following potential,
>   $$
> \vec{A}=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{B}\times\vec{r})
> $$
>   I want to evaluate the value of i) $[r_{i},\dot{p}_{j}]$ and ii) $[p_{i},\dot{p_{j}}]$ if ''$[a,b]$'' means Poisson Brackets of $a$ and $b$. Here $B$, $r$, $p$ are the magnetic field, vector position and linear momentum, respectively.

The Lagrangian of the system is given by

$$
L=\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}+\frac{q}{2}\vec{v}\cdot (\vec{B} \times \vec{r}) \hspace{30mm} (1)
$$

hence,

$$
\vec{v}=\frac{\vec{p}}{m}-\frac{q}{2m}(\vec{B}\times \vec{r}) \hspace{30mm} (2)
$$

and the Hamiltonian

$$
H=\frac{1}{2m}\left(\vec{p} -\frac{q}{2}(\vec{B}\times \vec{r}) \right)^{2} \hspace{30mm} (3)
$$

therefore

$$
\dot{p}_{j}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_{j}}=-\frac{1}{m}(\vec{p}-\frac{q}{2} (\vec{B}\times \vec{r}))\frac{\partial (\vec{p}-\frac{q}{2} (\vec{B}\times \vec{r}))}{\partial x_j}=+\frac{1}{m}(p_l-\frac{q}{2}\epsilon_{lmn}B_{m}x_{n})(\frac{q}{2}\epsilon_{lmj}B_{m}) \hspace{10mm}(4)
$$

**i)** 
$$
[x_{i},\dot{p}_{j}]=\frac{q}{2}\epsilon_{lmj}B_{m}[x_{i},\frac{1}{m}(p_l-\frac{q}{2}\epsilon_{lmn}B_{m}x_{n})]=\frac{q}{2m}\epsilon_{lmj}B_{m}\delta_{il}+0=+\frac{q}{2m}\epsilon_{imj}B_{m}.
$$

**ii)** 
$$
[p_i,\dot{p}_{a}]=\frac{q}{2m}\epsilon_{lmj}B_{m}\delta_{il}[p_{i},(p_a-\frac{q}{2}\epsilon_{abc}B_{b}x_{c})]=0+\frac{q}{2m}\epsilon_{lmj}B_{m}\cdot(-\frac{q}{2}\epsilon_{abc}B_{b})(-\delta_{ic})=
$$
$$
=+\frac{q^{2}}{4m}\epsilon_{lmj}B_{m}\cdot\epsilon_{abi}B_{b}=\frac{q^{2}}{4m}\epsilon_{lmj} \cdot \epsilon_{abi} \cdot B_{b}B_{m} \hspace{50mm}
$$

Could someone tell me if my computations are right or correct me?